# Python Recursion - Need Help Solving Code

Tags: python, recursion, boolean

I need help with the below code. What needs to go in the blanks to achieve the correct boolean outcomes?

Fill in the blanks to make the is_power_of function return whether the number is a power of the given base. Note: base is assumed to be a positive number. Tip: for functions that return a boolean value, you can return the result of a comparison.

```
def is_power_of(number, base):
  # Base case: when number is smaller than base.
  if number < base:
    # If number is equal to 1, it's a power (base**0).
    return __

  # Recursive case: keep dividing number by base.
  return is_power_of(__, ___)

print(is_power_of(8,2)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of(64,4)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of(70,10)) # Should be False
```

I am struggling to understand the foundations of recursion and how to look at this code piece by piece to find the answers. Please help and shed any knowledge that will help me improve understanding the code. I have tried returning "number", and also dividing number by base, but I can't figure out how to properly input it into the code and receive a boolean result rather than numerical.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. The Idea is, that you check if the number is devisible by the base. In this is the case, you can use the same function again to check if the result is also devisible by the base. If you can continue this until `number/base ==1` you can return `True`

Comment: I saw someone post this same question a few hours ago, I see the students are utilizing Stack Overflow to its fullest lol

Comment: There is not enough code in your function to give you the correct result even if you fill in the blanks

Comment: @Brock you must be new here ;)

Comment: Here's a free book on recursion that you may find helpful https://inventwithpython.com/recursion/

Answer (score 0):

Good evening, it seems to be an exercise or a homework assignment so I won't give you the answer directly, but I can help you understand if you want.

First, let's take a look at your problem:

Your goal here is to determine if a number is a power of another number, which means you want to find out if, by taking a base y, your number n can be written as x^t with t being a positive integer.

So if your number can be written as x^t, then it can be written as x * x * x * ... * x with x repeated t times.

Now, how can we adapt this to a recursive function?

The goal is to find a recursion termination condition, which is represented by your line:

```
if number < base:
    # If number is equal to 1, it's a power (base**0).
    return __
```

And if not, you continue with new parameters given by this comment:

```
# Recursive case: keep dividing number by base.
```

So you have the body of your recursive logic, now the final step is to understand how you will reason to understand this recursive system.

So, to give you an example and let you generalize it so that you can still understand the result:

If I want to know if 256 is a power of 4, how do I do it?

Well, I know that 256 = 4^4, but that won't always be the case, so I'll think recursively.

The idea is to say that if a number is a power of 4, then by dividing it successively by 4, I will end up with 1. Here: 256 => 64 => 16 => 4 => 1, and we can prove that this is true for all power-of-4 numbers, so your goal here will be to apply this logic in your recursive function.

Do you understand a bit better or do you need more detail on another point?